# Homebrew update keep complaining about git-fls but which repos are the trouble

Tags: git, homebrew, git-lfs

I can't seem to get homebrew to work properly anymore. Have tried to [uninstall and install it](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew). But it keeps throwing me this error about `git lfs` and I can't see where it comes from.

I'm all out of ideas - this is what I have done so far:

```
❯ git lfs install
Git LFS initialized.

❯ brew update --verbose
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/caskformula/homebrew-caskformula...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-bundle...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core...
Checking if we need to fetch /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services...
Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew...
Updating /usr/local/Homebrew...
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Switched to and reset branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/post-checkout.

Switched to and reset branch 'stable'

This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/post-checkout.

Current branch stable is up to date.

Already up-to-date.
```

```
❯ cat .gitconfig
[core]
    editor = code --wait
    excludesfile = /Users/norfeldt/.gitignore_global
    hooksPath = /Users/norfeldt/Dropbox/Code/Git/hooks

    quotepath = false
    # The default value is true.

    precomposeunicode = true 
    # Only used by Mac OS implementation of Git.

    ...

[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = true
[diff]
    ...
```

```
❯ cat Dropbox/Code/Git/hooks/pre-push
#!/bin/sh
command echo $PWD
command -v git-lfs >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/pre-push.\n"; exit 2; }
git lfs pre-push "$@"
```

```
❯ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you an update run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/.
```

Comment: I don't see any "error". What's not working? — By the way it looks to me like the answer is here: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/4988

Comment: Also this is not a programming question, should be on AskDifferent or similar.

Comment: I have looked at the issue, you are linking to, so many times. The solution is to go to the repo and enable git lfs for that. But as mentioned I can't see which and where the repos with the issue are

Comment: If I try to 'brew tap wix/brew' it fails (and tells me a git-lfs on the way out)

Comment: I presume that the repo in question is brew itself?

Comment: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/git-lfs

Comment: I tried `brew reinstall git-lfs` (and `git lfs install` and `sudo git lfs install --system`) and now it seems to work... ‍♂️  I did try that before I uninstalled and installed brew. It works now. @fredrik I can mark it as an solution if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution appeared to be

```
$ cd $(brew --repo)/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/.git/hooks
$ git-lfs uninstall
```

https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/32#discussioncomment-92562

Comment: I am trying your solution, but it appears I don't even have `git-lfs` installed:

`-bash: git-lfs: command not found`

Comment: It might be that the changes git-lfs makes to your git hooks hasn't been reverted when you uninstalled it

Comment: This should have been marked as the accepted answer (even if it is your own question)

Comment: Finally this worked for me